# Include chapter number in citation using biblatex

Tags: biblatex, citing

I'm currently writing my thesis and would like to have my references include the chapter number in which they are cited.

For example, citation 1 of chapter 2 becomes [2.1] and so on...

I'm using biblatex to handle the bibliography so tried to find help in the documentation—bad idea, I'm even more confused!

If it helps, each chapter has its own .bib file.